# How can I probe optimal datatype from existing MySQL columns with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sqldatatypes

I have a MySQL table with ~400 columns

The columns are accumulated from external data so **I don't really have control over the count initially at least**

In the interest of avoiding errors whilst making **columns, these are just TEXT datatype** and now have all of the rows that they will likely ever need

I am now trying to optimise the data, which I have an idea of how to do, but again, I want to try to avoid errors if possible

**TLDR: I would like to iterate each column and determine the datatype (i.e. TINYINT, INT, VARCHAR(?), CHAR(?), BOOLEAN, TEXT, etc.)**

I understand how to loop over the data, but I am more concerned about accuracy and ensuring data integrity, so what I am asking for is if anyone knows any resources or links to existing code that will perform this exact function?

I don't want to miss any nuances or special cases for any of these data types, and it just makes sense not to reinvent the wheel if a resource exists?

Comment: 400 columns? sounds like "good design" at first glance...

Comment: As I mentioned this is gathered from an external source, I am trying to optimise the data types first, then look to move columns with not many values out into their own cross-reference table, I imagine 150 columns would be the final amount, but they still should have correct data types after being moved

Comment: Never met such a tool. But since you have a pretty limited set of possible types to get data converted into, I don't think there are too many difficulties with determining what data is and selecting a proper data type. Lets say, meeting a 'this is a string' value, you throw away all the numeric types for column given. When all rows are analyzed, you should be having a set of possible types to select from. Using predefined priority (i.e. varchar has higher priority than text) you pick a final type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much browsing, and investigating Tableschema, it seemed that the fastest way to solve the problem would be to iterate through the data

Basic overview as I can't provide the actual code, but this should be enough to save someone a lot of time in future - also make sure to zero out or null everything before each loop of columns

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1G');

$stmt = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table`");
//...


foreach($columns as $column){
    $int = true;
    $decimal = true;
    $boolean = true;
    $intmax = 0;
    $intneg = false;
    $integer_part = 0;
    $decimal_part = 0;
    $decimal_neg = false;
    $consistent_len = 0;
    $consistent_strlen = null;
    $nullable = false;
    $boolean_counter = 0;
    $boolean_array = array();
    $strlen = 0;

    $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT `$column` FROM `table`");
    //...
    foreach($rowdata as $line){
        if(empty($line)){
            $nullable = true;
            continue;
        }
        else{
            $data = trim($line);
        }
        // turn off $int, $decimal, $boolean to false based on criteria
        // mb_strlen($data, 'UTF-8'); helpful for varchar multibyte
    }
    // Check order of preference > BOOLEAN > INT (Variants) > DECIMAL > CHAR > VARCHAR > TEXT

    // define $type, $unsigned, $is_null

    $column_type = $type.$unsigned.$is_null;
    $alter_query = "ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `$column` $column_type";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for the [information_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html).

This query does what you need.

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'whatever_table_name'
   AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
 ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

Good interactive tools like [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) and [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) can also display the metadata (data describing data) you need in a useful form.

Another possible trick: export a random selection of a few thousand rows to a .csv file and import it into Excel or LibreOffice Calc. Those programs will try to guess the data types.

The interactive tools, or the command-line tool, can do the exporting. The query to get the randomly selected rows into a .csv file is something like

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1000)
  INTO OUTFILE 'sample.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This assumes `id` is a primary key.

This will be a bit slow, so don't do it too often.

Comment: The column_type are all TEXT as I mentioned, I will have to iterate the actual data itself in order to discover the appropriate data type

Comment: Exporting to excel might be the best way as you mention, I will try that if I can't find an exact solution - I hoped maybe this problem had been encountered before

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard problem - there are a few [options](https://hackersandslackers.com/infer-datatypes-from-csvs-to-create/) available to you. The most complete solution I've found is in Python, and called [Tableschema](https://github.com/frictionlessdata/tableschema-py). You feed it data - CSV is easiest - and then ask it to infer the schema.

So, you could use @o.jones's code to export a random 1000 rows to CSV, then feed that into Tableschema, and use that to create a table with more accurate field types.

Comment: I found this problem quite interesting and SQL-wise nothing really exists if we wanted to do it dynamically across large number of columns. I'm not Python dev but I installed Tableschema, exported 10MB from a table with 75 columns - I like the simplicity of the tool but even though my data wasn't quoted, it inferred everything as text, despite some clear date columns or numbers (timestamps) (booleans and arrays were fine). Looking forward to your results @user16861522

Comment: @Moseleyi provided my solution as answer, ended up doing the hard way but hopefully overview of it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    MIN(col1), MAX(col1) MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(col1)),
    MIN(col2), MAX(col2) MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(col2)),
    ...
   FROM tbl;
```

That will give you some feel for the datatypes and their sizes.  (Do substitute the actual column names above.)

- If both max and min look numeric and max len is small, then *probably* some numeric type.

  - Consider `DECIMAL`/`FLOAT` if you see certain punctuation.
  - Consider `UNSIGNED` if neither the max nor min look negative.
- If max or min are non-numeric and the max len is under 100, use twice the max len in `VARCHAR(...)`.
- If max or min are non-numeric with a bigger max len, use some variation of `TEXT`.

There is doubtless a REGEXP that would help distinguish numeric from string.  Something like

```
col1 REGEXP '^[0-9]$'      -- some size of INT UNSIGNED
col1 REGEXP '^[-+0-9]$'    -- some size of INT SIGNED
col1 REGEXP '^[-+0-9.]$'   -- DECIMAL(..., ...)
col1 REGEXP '^[-+0-9.e]$'  -- FLOAT or DOUBLE
```

Variations:

```
TINYINT  SMALLINT  MEDIUMINT  INT  BIGINT
TEXT  MEDIUMTEXT  LONGTEXT  (don't use TINYTEXT)
```

You could query `information_schema.COLUMNS` to find the column names and automatically generate the above `SELECT`.  (I would not bother unless you have lots of columns to investigate.)

The above does not include `BINARY`/`BLOB`, character sets, `(m,n)` for `DECIMAL`, `ENUM`.